# bit.dev with react less styles

Tags: reactjs, bit.dev

I wanna use **bit.dev** as my react shared components store but I've stacked with compiling less files to css. I'm using **create-react-app** with **customize-cra** (to override CRA config without ejecting).

Here is my **config-overrides.js** file:

```
const { override, addLessLoader } = require('customize-cra');
module.exports = override(addLessLoader());
```

Here is my bit config from **package.json**:

```
"bit": {
  "env": {
    "compiler": "bit.envs/compilers/react@1.0.11"
  },
  "componentsDefaultDirectory": "components/{name}",
  "packageManager": "yarn",
  "defaultScope": "demkovych.spone-ui"
}
```

After **bit build** command finished, I still got **.less** file instead of **.css**. 
Any suggestion how to use scss/less with bit.dev?

Comment: You find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Right now the react compiler is only transpiling the code to plain javascript. The target application (consuming project) should compile the LESS files.

Comment: I know, my compiler transpilled it to less, but looks like bit has they own react compiler :(